# Thread subclass/implements Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to print both objects, `MyThread t=new MyThread();` prints Thread[Thread-0,5,main] & `MyRunnable r=new MyRunnable();` prints Thread.MyRunnable@34cd54.

What's significance of it?

Comment: Check out `Object#toString()` method that all classes inherit.

Comment: What research have you done?  What documentation have you read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's significance of it?

Not much, Thread is a class which has a toString() methods and you Runnable is an interface which uses the default Object.toString()